# How to generate a random string of letters and numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, random

I have been using this code:

```
function stringGen()
{
    var text = " ";

    var charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < len; i++ )
        text += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length));

    return text;
}
```

But so far, it has not been working, like at all. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: You never define `len`

Comment: If you are using `Lodash` or `Underscore`, then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript/36734713#36734713

Answer (score 32):

You missed the parameter `len`.

```js
function stringGen(len) {
  var text = "";
  
  var charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    text += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length));
  
  return text;
}

console.log(stringGen(3));
```

This would give you something like "a1z".

Comment: +1 This one looks more correct than mine as it allows you to define the length of the string you need.

Answer (score 10):

A pretty one-liner would be:

```
Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, length)
```

Or if you need a str that is longer than 10/11 characters:

```
function generateRandAlphaNumStr(len) {
  var rdmString = "";
  for( ; rdmString.length < len; rdmString  += Math.random().toString(36).substr(2));
  return  rdmString.substr(0, len);

}
```

Comment: The maximum `length` is `11` and, depending on the random number generated, sometimes you get `10` characters instead.

Comment: Yea that's true, good point :)

Comment: Now fixed for "unlimited" length.

Comment: If conciseness was your aim, you could put the `var rdmString = ""` into the first part of the `for` loop

Comment: Instead of substring, you can better use "slice()". For eg, `Math.random().toString(34).slice(2);`

Answer (score 2):

Just as alternative:

```
var len = 20,
    str = '';

while( len-- ) {
    str += String.fromCharCode( 48 + ~~(Math.random() * 42) );
}

console.log( str );
```

Comment: This is more than alphanumeric. Anyway the OP must have copied the function somewhere.

Comment: @Antony true, I was a little lazy. To get pure alpha nummericals we would need to limit the ascii range more. However, I felt like this is a more generic approach as having a pre-defined map of characters.

Answer (score 1):

Your len variable is undefined. Either pass it in as a parameter, or set it to something.

```
function stringGen(len)
{
    var text = " ";

    var charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < len; i++ )
        text += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length));

    return text;
}
alert(stringGen(5));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rg7Z3/